# In functional programming, why IO's join method should run the unsafePerformIO twice?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, monads

[In DrBoolean's Gitbook](https://drboolean.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide/content/ch9.html#mixing-metaphors), there are several examples explaining monad, for Maybe:

```
Maybe.prototype.join = function() {
  return this.isNothing() ? Maybe.of(null) : this.__value;
}
```

And for IO:

```
IO.prototype.join = function() {
  var thiz = this;
  return new IO(function() {
    return thiz.unsafePerformIO().unsafePerformIO();
  });
};
```

I am wondering why IO should run unsafePerformIO twice to return a new IO instead of just `return this.unsafePerformIO()`?

Comment: The explanation is in the document, copy-pasting the document here wouldn't help you. It's because they have nested `IO` objects, you have to 'peel off' the layers. Maybe there is some other part of the code you don't understand already which makes this unclear?

Comment: Yes, this is counter-intuitive. When you apply `join` it doesn't perform the join operation but just adds another monadic context, i.e. another thunk. The join operation is itself deferred.

Comment: In other words, `join` first does the opposite of what you're expecting and defers the actual join operation until the impure computation is actually executed. `join` must then take care of the context, which it has added itself.

Comment: Do you understand how `IO.prototype.map` works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**no IO until I say so**

In the case of IO, it's important that we do not execute any IO until desired – In the examples below, pay particular attention to the order of the output lines

```js
// IO
const IO = function (f) {
  this.unsafePerformIO = f
}

IO.of = function (x) {
  return new IO(() => x)
}

IO.prototype.join = function () {
  return this.unsafePerformIO()
}

// your main program
const main = function (m) {
  console.log('you should not see anything above this line')
  console.log('program result is:', m.unsafePerformIO())
}

// IO (IO (something))
const m = new IO(() => {
  console.log('joining...')
  return IO.of(5)
})

// run it
main(m.join())
```

Above, `joining...` appears *earlier* than we expected/desired – Now compare that to the correct `IO.join` implementation – *all* effects are deferred until `unsafePerformIO` is called on the outermost IO.

---

**box again, unbox twice**

In general, all IO operations add a new box around the deferred computation. For `join` specifically, we still have to add a new box, but the operation is to unbox twice, so we still effectively go from 2 levels of nesting down to 1.

```js
// IO
const IO = function (f) {
  this.unsafePerformIO = f
}

IO.of = function (x) {
  return new IO(() => x)
}

IO.prototype.join = function () {
  return new IO(() => this.unsafePerformIO().unsafePerformIO())
}

// your main program
const main = function (m) {
  console.log('you should not see anything above this line')
  console.log('program result is:', m.unsafePerformIO())
}

// IO (IO (something))
const m = new IO(() => {
  console.log('joining...')
  return IO.of(5)
})

// run it
main(m.join())
```

---

**not just IO**

It's arguable that this box-again-unbox-twice approach for `join` is suitable for other monads too

```js
function Maybe (x) {
  this.value = x
}

Maybe.of = function (x) {
  return new Maybe(x)
}

Maybe.prototype.join = function () {
  // assumes that this.value is a Maybe
  // but what if it's not?
  return this.value;
}

Maybe.prototype.toString = function () {
  return `Maybe(${this.value})`
}

const m = Maybe.of(Maybe.of(5))
console.log("m               == %s", m)
console.log("m.join()        == %s", m.join())

// hmm... now it seems `.join` can return a non-Maybe??
console.log("m.join().join() == %s", m.join().join())
```

Above, it appears as tho `Maybe.join` will sometimes return a Maybe, and other times it could simply return the boxed value. Because it doesn't guarantee that a Maybe is returned, it makes it harder to rely upon it's behaviour

Now, compare that to the box-again-unbox-twice approach below

```js
function Maybe (x) {
  this.value = x
}

Maybe.of = function (x) {
  return new Maybe(x)
}

Maybe.prototype.join = function () {
  // box again, unbox twice
  // guaranteed to return a Maybe
  return Maybe.of(this.value.value)
}

Maybe.prototype.toString = function () {
  return `Maybe(${this.value})`
}

const m = Maybe.of(Maybe.of(5))
console.log("m               == %s", m)

// this still works as intended
console.log("m.join()        == %s", m.join())

// here join still returns a Maybe as expected,
// but the inner value `undefined` reveals a different kind of problem
console.log("m.join().join() == %s", m.join().join())
```

---

**weakly-typed JavaScript**

In the above example, our `Maybe(Maybe(Number))` transformed into `Maybe(Maybe(undefined))` which would result in an error in a strongly-typed language. However, in the case of JavaScript, no such error will be apparent until you try to work with `undefined` where you were actually expecting a `5` – This is a different kind of problem, but I personally favour a known codomain (return type) over one that I have to type-check later.

Of course we could fix this problem by doing a type-check inside join itself, but now Maybe is impure and can throw errors at runtime.

```
Maybe.prototype.join = function () {
  if (this.value instanceof Maybe)
    return this.value
  else
    throw TypeError ('non-Maybe cannot be joined')
}
```

Sadly, this is where JavaScript breaks down for some aspects of functional programming. There is trade-offs for each implementation of `Maybe.join` here, so you'll have to pick what works best for you.

---

**some sort of idempotence**

Perhaps you could even write `Maybe.join` like a sort of idempotent function; it will join if it can, otherwise it will just return itself – Now you get the guaranteed `Maybe` return type and no possibility for a runtime error

```
Maybe.prototype.join = function () {
  if (this.value instanceof Maybe)
    return this.value
  else
    return this
}
```

However, the below program is now validated by this implementation

```
// should this be allowed?
Maybe.of(Maybe.of(5)).join().join().join().join().join() // => Maybe(5)
```

Trade-offs, trade-offs, trade-offs. Pick your poison or pick PureScript ^_^

Comment: Do you think it is useful to return a `Maybe(undefined)` when you actually have a bug in your code. `join` have to return a monad, otherwise it should either throw or return `undefined`. I am not sure yet what the semantics of `Maybe(undefined)` could be.

Comment: @ftor, not particularly useful, no – but this is where JS's type system breaks down. I've added some stuff about weakly-typed JS and a possible (sort of) idempotent implementation of `join`. Curious what you think.

Comment: @ftor, I agree with you re: throw/catch. I don't think the tolerant solution helps in building a semantically correct program. Ie, the ability to `join` a non-nested monad seems like a bad allowance.

Comment: Poison? No, let's go for PureScript!

Comment: @Bergi are you a fan? I'm just learning it and enjoying it so far. I'm yet to write anything very meaningful with it tho ^_^

Comment: @naomik I haven't really used it yet myself, but am reading the [tutorial](http://try.purescript.org/) currently. Looks like the type system is sufficiently advanced, I have yet to decide whether it's complex enough to be useful or too complex to be usable :-)